# Inline content in fancybox with arrows as gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using simple fancybox code to display inline content but I have multiple divs and want to display arrows to navigate right and left as a gallery. The fancybox itself works fine but there'r no arrows to display next and previous div so how could this happen?

```
<a href="#pro-1" rel="gallery" class="product">
<a href="#pro-2" rel="gallery" class="product">
<a href="#pro-3" rel="gallery" class="product">

<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="pro-1">
    <h1>title1 here</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="pro-2">
    <h1>title2 here</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="pro-3">
    <h1>title3 here</h1>
  </div>
</div>

$(function () {
  $("a.product").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/ue4kcsu8/

Comment: may be because the buttons files were missing from my code you can add yours as an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

included all fancybox files and upgraded to the newest version that solved the problem thanks to @JFK